# Softness of a foam roller for spine decompression and posture issues

Tags: back, foam-rolling

For most of my life I've had terrible posture. I've had a mostly sedentary lifestyle, my back arches when I sit (slouching), a forward-head posture when I walk. It does not cause me any pains yet (47yo) although I do sometimes feel a need to lie down for what I think achieves spine decompression.

I have recently decided I want to start doing a bunch of different exercises to improve my core strength, pay more attention to posture, and generally be a bit more careful with my back. By doing this, I am hoping I can avoid more serious issues later on.

One of the things I'd like to get is a foam roller. The heaviest intended use is to lay down on it length-wise. Several articles online and videos on YouTube have suggested getting a 36" foam roller for this purpose.

My main concern is what density I should be getting. I am a big guy (6'3", 200lbs/193cm, 93kg) and am debating between getting the OPTP Soft and Standard density rollers. Because I can't get quality products where I live, I need to ask a friend to bring one over from the US and so I need to get it right.

I'd appreciate any recommendations on which density to get for the intended use / my body weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nice that you take steps to boost your posture and core strength! A foam roller will be a useful gizmo for stretching and massaging muscles, further as for supporting correct body alignment.

As a general rule, a firmer foam roller could also be a lot of appropriate for supporting your weight and providing the required support for exercises like plank variations, whereas a softer foam roller could also be softer for stretching and massaging muscles.

Given your weight and therefore the supposed use of the froth roller (lying down length-wise), you'll wish to think about obtaining a firmer foam roller like the OPTP commonplace density roller. this may} facilitate make sure that the froth roller can offer adequate support for your weight and permit you to perform exercises safely.

It's always an honest plan to start out with a softer foam roller and step by step workout to a firmer one, if needed, as your muscles become stronger and a lot of at home with the froth roller. you'll additionally wish to think about consulting with a therapist or different fitness skilled to see the most effective foam roller density and exercises for your specific wants and goals.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).